# Group axioms are not a complete theory

Tags: group-theory, model-theory

Can anybody point me to a simple way to show that the three axioms for a group (associativity, neutral element, symmetrical element) do not form a complete theory

Comment: You can extend them with either $\forall x,y(xy=yx)$ or its negation.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. My question was not how to reach a complete theory, but how to simply show it is not complete.

Comment: I answered your question. My comment doesn’t tell you how to reach a complete theory; it tells you how to show that it is not complete. Showing that it has two incompatible extensions *is* a proof that it is not complete.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understand now.

Comment: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 3):

There are a three first order properties undecided by the theory of groups:

- Commutativity.
- Presence of $p$ torsion.
- Divisibility by $p$.

If we decide these to form the theory of torsion free divisible abelian groups we get a theory that is complete.  Although there are many other ways to get complete theories.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. My question was not how to reach a complete theory, but how to simply show it is not complete

Comment: To show a theory is not complete you must show that it does not decide some sentence. As Scott and Schipperus have both pointed out, the sentence $\forall x\forall y(xy=yx)$ is one such sentence.

Comment: @Sachama Yes, I know, I had hoped to give you a list of statements that could not be decided by theory of groups, my completness remarks were an afterthought, but they show that in one sense the list is complete.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very useful.